# Variable or function undefined

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am trying to implement following in MATLAB,

```
n1 = 6; 
n2 = 1;
n3=0.1;
global ps

ps=zeros(3,15);
[R,t,d]=model(n1,n2,n3);
ps=R;
[x, fval] = fmincon(@Obj,[1/3,1/3, 1/3],[],[],[],[],[],[],@cons);


function f = Obj(x)
f = x(1)^2+x(2)^3+x(3)^4;

function [c, ceq] = cons(x)
c=[];
ceq(1) = sum(ps(1,:))*x(1)+sum(ps(2,:))*x(2)+sum(ps(3,:))*x(3) - (sum(d(1,:)));
ceq(2) = sum(x) - 4;
```

I'm getting following error, what is wrong here?

```
variable or function 'ps' undefined
```

Comment: Rolled back to original as it seems there was an accidental deletion of half the code. (Even messed up the formatting a bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot run your lines of code, but I think you have to put

```
global ps
```

in your `function cons` to inform Matlab that you are referring to the global `ps`. More information on global variables can be found here: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/global.html

EDIT: For a cleaner design, you should take into account horchler's advice:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/20721808/3060323

Comment: I've added global ps to my main script. Do you mean I need to add it to constraint file as well?

Comment: @user3125389, yes, the `global` command has to be given in each workspace in which you'd like to access the global variable.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to and definitelty [*should not* use global variables](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/51946-systematic-do-not-use-global-don-t-use-eval) for this. It is a very bad habit and [inefficient to boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888899/global-could-be-very-inefficient). Any time you think about using `global` you should ask yourself if there is another way and search for it. It is only in the very very rare case that globals are needed/helpful (usually in large codebases such as toolboxes).

In your case, you should pass your `ps` variable in as a parameter by creating an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html). First define your `cons` function like this so that it takes in a parameter argument:

```
function [c, ceq] = cons(x,ps)
```

Then create the anonymous function with one input (`x`) and one captured parameter (the variable `ps`, which needs to be defined before this):

```
[x, fval] = fmincon(@Obj,[1/3,1/3, 1/3],[],[],[],[],[],[],@(x)cons(x,ps));
```

Alternatively you can save a handle to the anonymous function and pass that in:

```
cfun = @(x)cons(x,ps);
[x, fval] = fmincon(@Obj,[1/3,1/3, 1/3],[],[],[],[],[],[],cfun);
```

Here's a [blog post from The MathWorks with other bad habits](http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2010/03/08/top-10-matlab-code-practices-that-make-me-cry/).

Comment: I completely agree, but still the accepted answer is the one that answers the question as posed.

Comment: @A.Donda: And mine doesn't? The question mentioned nothing about globals and even if it did, it would still be a bad idea that is easily corrected.

Comment: @horchler In the original version of the question, there was a `global ps` among the first lines of code, so I just wanted to give a hint on how to access that variable from inside another function. Without a doubt, your answer is the one that is cleaner, more enlightening and more complete, and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @horchler, as I said, I agree with your advice. But the question is "I'm getting following error, what is wrong here?", and the answer is that the `global` statement in the function is missing. In that sense, no, you don't answer the question – no offence intended. And I only made that comment because your original text seemed to suggest that @blackbird's answer was accepted undeservedly. That's not the case imho.

Comment: @blackbird: Thanks. That clarifies things, though I'm not sure why the OP deleted that line.