# Expose workspace of a called function to calling function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, configuration-files

For the sake of simplicity I am using MATLAB scripts as configuration files in my application. This way I can use the function `run` to load all variables into the workspace. Currently I am writing the code below out each and every time I need to load a configuration file.

```
configFile = [APP.PROJECT_DIR '/config/app.m'];
    if exist(configFile, 'file') ~= 2
        error('Missing configuration file for APP: [PROJECT ROOT DIR]/configFile/app.m')
    end
    run(configFile);
```

To reduce the amount of lines, I would like to place the above code in a standalone function. However if I do that the variables from the configuration file are loaded in that function instead of into the calling function. How could I manage to expose the workspace of a called function to the workspace of the calling function?

Basically what I want is the functionality of `run` + a check for file existince + custom error message if file does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Some possible (mutually exclusive) approaches:

- Make the function return those variables as outputs.
- Declare those variables as [`global`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/global.html).
- Use a script instead of a function. That would probably be my choice.
- If none of the above suits your needs, you can use [`evalin`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/evalin.html). [Not good practice](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html), though.

Comment: Globals are right up there in terms of [not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888899/global-could-be-very-inefficient) [good](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/51946-systematic-do-not-use-global-don-t-use-eval) [practice](http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2010/03/08/top-10-matlab-code-practices-that-make-me-cry/) except in very specialized cases, just like `eval`. This might be one of those cases. Another option is to re-write all code as a class using [OOP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/object-oriented-programming.html).

Comment: @horchler Thanks for the links. I didn't know globals were considered such bad practice, although they clearly mess things up

Answer (score 1):

You can save the data in the local workspace into a `.mat` file, and return the mat file name as the output of your defined function. Then you use the `load` function in your calling function. Below gives the hints:

```
load(userConfig(configFile))
```

In the definition of your config function:

```
function output_args = userConfig(input_args)
...
run(input_args)
output_args = [input_args,'at'];
save(output_args)
end
```

I suppose the string `configFile` is your `input_args` of the `userConfig` function.

I just privide a solution that you may want, even though I do not recommend that.