# Matlab ode45 vs. ode23, different solutions

Tags: matlab, ode, numerical-integration, ode45

I used `ode45` and `ode23` for a set of non-stiff differential equations. However, both methods converge to a slightly different solution. How can I find out which one is correct? See attached plot where blue is `ode45`, red is `ode23`. The dashed lines are the final values for each solver. Also, `ode15s` is a bit different (less than 1 m)...

[image]

Comment: 1. you could check the asymptotical value of the solution at `t=inf` on paper. 2. are you sure the equation is not stiff? Lot of things going on at the beginning 3. we're talking about 0.1% of an error. 4. Why are the initial values different? 5. why are there so few (sparse) time steps?

Comment: They're likely both "wrong" as you're using numerical integration. It's going to be hard to help without runnable code to replicate the issue. Also, why the dashed lines for the final values not the same as the actual final values at 10 seconds?

Comment: The x-axis represents the final values when chosen for a timestep of 10 seconds, 5 seconds, etc. So, x-axis isn't the time. It is just a simple ballistic missile trajectory calculation with air resistance.

Comment: Hmm...what *kind* of resistance? There's a chance you can solve it on paper.

Comment: http://www.usna.edu/Users/mecheng/ratcliff/EM375/labs/07Project/ProjectileTheory.pdf this is the problem i'am trying to solve :)

Comment: How exactly are you "choosing a time step". Matlab's ODE solvers are adaptive so one specifies tolerances (it's quite hard to set a true fixed step size with them).

Comment: @horchler That's true, i just found out that when setting a timestep Matlab interpolates its ODE solutions to 'simulate' your own timestep. I have been playing with some tolerance options, but so far no differences at all... Which is strange because i have set (I think...) my tolerance at 'AbsTol' 1e-10....

Comment: You need to set the relative tolerance to a smaller value, not the absolute tolerance. Then `ode23` and `ode45` will converge to closer values after the same amount of time.

Comment: @horchler, please write your last answer below, so I could accept it as the correct answer. Now all ODE's get me the same answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matlab's ODE solvers are [adaptive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_stepsize) so one specifies tolerances rather than a step size (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21861868/2278029)). Given the code in the [PDF linked in the comments](http://www.usna.edu/Users/mecheng/ratcliff/EM375/labs/07Project/ProjectileTheory.pdf), if you specify a smaller value for the relative tolerance, the solutions from `ode45` and `ode23` will converge after the same amount of time. You can use [`odeset`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html) to set [`'RelTol'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html#zmw57dd0e525830):

```
...
opts = odeset('RelTol', 1e-12);
[t, oput] = ode23(@(t,y)secondode(t,y,C,g), tspan, IC, opts);
...
```

Note that I also got rid of the global variables used in the linked code (they're [bad](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/51946-systematic-do-not-use-global-don-t-use-eval) and [inefficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888899/global-could-be-very-inefficient)). You also need to change the function definition for `secondode` to:

```
function z = secondode(t, indata, C, g)
...
```